# How to correctly output json as object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vuew application which generates an array which I want to send to my Spring boot application to save to a db.
The use case is like this. The user can add as many Times objects as he wants which consists of: Date,start and endtime.

but the json output is like this:

```
[
   {
      "meetingName":"",
      "meetingTime":[
         [
            {
               "date":"2021-05-31",
               "startTime":"15:30",
               "endTime":"16:30"
            },
         ],
         [
            {
               "date":"2021-06-22",
               "startTime":"15:30",
               "endTime":"16:30"
            },
             
            {
               "date":"2021-06-22",
               "startTime":"15:30",
               "endTime":"16:30"
            },

         ]
      ]
   }
]
```

But what I want to achieve is an output like this:

```
 {
      "meetingName":"",
      "meetingTime":[
         
            {
               "date":"2021-05-31",
               "startTime":"15:30",
               "endTime":"16:30"
            },
            {
               "date":"2021-05-31",
               "startTime":"17:30",
               "endTime":"18:30"
            },
          {
               "date":"2021-06-22",
               "startTime":"15:30",
               "endTime":"16:30"
            },
         ]
      
   }
```

This is how I generate my array:

```
<script>
import DatePickerComponent from "@/components/DatePickerComponent";

export default {
  name: "GenerateMeetingSettings",

  data: () => ({
    selectedTime: [],
    finalMeeting: [],
    datesFinal: [{meetingName: "", meetingPw:"",
      meetingTime: []}] ,
    dates: new Date().toISOString().substr(0,10),
    meetingSettingUrl: "",
    meetingPW: "",     
  })
,

  methods:{

    addTimeFields(){
      this.selectedTime.push({
        date: this.dates,
        startTime:"",
        endTime: "",
      })
    },
    saveDateAndTIme(e) {
        this.datesFinal[0].meetingTime.push(this.selectedTime),

          this.selectedTime = []


    },
```

Could someone please look at my code and point out what my mistake is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rplace this :

```
this.datesFinal[0].meetingTime.push(this.selectedTime)
```

with this:

```
this.datesFinal[0].meetingTime = [...this.datesFinal[0].meetingTime, ...this.selectedTime]
```

Comment: amazing it worked, can u explain me the difference between your code and my push method?

Comment: Sure 
selectedTime is an array and you are pushing array into another array. 
But what you actually want is to merge two arrays (selectedTime, meetingTime) into one flat array. 
If you are not familiar with spread operator you can use this as well:
[].concat(selectedTime, meetingTime)

Comment: thanks for the nice expllanation. But one question. Is it possible to delete the outer [] which take the whole json like in the first example?

Comment: yes do these changes :
datesFinal: { {meetingName: "", meetingPw:"",
      meetingTime: []} } (inside data)
then ->
this.datesFinal.meetingTime = [...this.datesFinal.meetingTime, ...this.selectedTime]

Comment: Hi, I tried to do this: datesFinal: { {meetingName: "", meetingPw:"", meetingTime: []} } but this gives an error. Identifier or String numerical expected. Is the error, I tried to do this inside data. Instead of this: datesFinal: [{meetingName: "", meetingPw:"",
      meetingTime: []}] ,

Comment: Just noticed if you do what you did with one {} on the outside it works. Maybe you had a typo?

Comment: Yes sorry for that I didn't notice